# After contacting a manager on the social network and getting positive feedback he is not responding. What next?

Tags: professionalism, social-media

I was looking for possible contacts in my "dream company" on the social network. I have found an it-manager that is currently looking for new employees (he wrote it on his profile page) for the field where I am an professional. I sent him a message with a short description of my work expirience and he quickly replied asking for my full CV and my availability for the call. On the next day I sent my resume and a proposal for the call. 
That was on Tuesday. Today is Saturday and I have no answer from him.

Question: what could be my next step in this conversation? Wait until he answers or just be active and ask? I would like to know whether he still interested to stay in touch with me.

Comment: It is not a 'hiring manager', It is an IT-manager. And it is not a 'normal' hiring prozess with usual waiting times and a clear contact procedure.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you are waiting for a response from the company, so this question is a duplicate of the other. You can call him hiring manager or IT manager or some other manager, that doesn't make any difference. Also, if you think that a "normal" hiring process has *well-defined* waiting times and clear contact procedures, you need to see more of the world. What you have described in the question is as "normal" as a hiring process can get.

Comment: @Happy Hmm, believe me I know what I say. I have more that 15 years expirience with hiring managers and other hight-ups. The difference is the HR have a clear hiring process, they don't care how good you are. All they need to know is how good you will fit into the team and how clear is your social level and education grade. On the other hand for IT-manager is more interesting to know which proffesional knowledge have the candidate and so on. So I think you need to see more of the world man.

Comment: Well, that's great to know, bro. I haven't seen that much of the world, but in the world that I have seen, 15-years experienced people are known to wait longer than 4 days before wondering whether the "IT manager" is still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can certainly seem like an eternity when you are waiting for a response. It's very likely he is just busy and hasn't had a chance to respond, especially given the relatively small amount of time that has elapsed.

I suggest that you follow up *one time*, on the one-week mark.  Say something like this:

> I'm just following up to see if you received the CV that I sent on
>   ____, and if you have any questions. I'd really like to explore this opportunity with your company  as it seems like it could be a great
>   fit.  If there is someone else I should contact, please let me know.
>
> Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Wouldn't hurt to include the CV again, just for his convenience.

If you get nothing back but are pretty sure the message was delivered, it's probably best to move on to other channels (HR, perhaps), or just let this one go.

Feedback is something everyone wants in a situation like this, but unfortunately there are many, many reasons why it's unlikely to happen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will wait a couple of days and then will send a new message like you said.

Comment: Follow up message is great but I would not include CV in the message, personally.